# AlertDialog with textfield and single choice list

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I have an `AlertDialog` that has two `EditText` fields. I would like to replace the second `EditText` field with a single choice list, but I can't seem to get it to work. 
Here's my code so far:

```
            //dialog box
            // Init the dialog object
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MapsActivity.this);
            builder.setTitle("Enter name and type");

            // Set up the input
            final EditText input_name = new EditText(MyActivity.this);
            final EditText input_type = new EditText(MyActivity.this);

            // Specify the type of input expected;
            input_name.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
            input_type.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);

            LinearLayout ll=new LinearLayout(MyActivity.this);
            ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
            ll.addView(input_name);
            ll.addView(input_type);
            ll.addView(input_type_list);

            builder.setView(ll);
            // Set up the buttons
            builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    String description;
                    String type;
                    description = input_name.getText().toString();
                    type = input_type.getText().toString();

                    // display toast message
                    Context context = getApplicationContext();
                    CharSequence text = description + " Added!";
                    int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;
                    Toast.makeText(context, text, duration).show();
                    //end display toast message
                }
            });
            builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });

            builder.show();
```

I've seen the doc's about a single choice list, but I also want to have a text field too.

My background is in C/C++ and most of the other posts I've seen involve setting the layouts in `xml` files which I'm not that familiar with.

Ideally, I would like to do something like this:

```
    final ListView input_type_list = new ListView(MapsActivity.this);
    final String[] list_strings = {"a", "b", "c"};
```

and instead of the `EditText input_type`, show a list.

I'm sorry if my question is naive or if there's a standard way of doing this which I've missed, but I would appreciate if anyone could help me or point to the right direction.

Comment: have you considered just using a custom dialog?

Comment: What do you mean by a single choice list?

Comment: @RohitSharma, a list of these three choices where I can pick one

Comment: Then why not to use spinner

Comment: @RohitSharma, I don't know what spinner is, checking it right now

Comment: @RohitSharma actually spinner sounds better, can I combine it with a text field?

Comment: Did not get what do you mean by combine it with a text field?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100904/discussion-between-helplesskirk-and-rohit-sharma).